# Checking Non-Word Files Back In

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, versioning, check-out

I'm contemplating using SharePoint to manage shared files, including keeping a version history, and requiring check-out (the files contain certain modelling data). In SharePoint 2010, I can upload non-doc files to a SharePoint Document Library, and can require check-out, but it's not clear how to check back in an edited file. I can select "check in" in SharePoint, but it's not clear where it's checking it in from (the orignal save location?), and changes don't seem to have registered.

1. How can I check a file back in that is not edited in Word?
2. Is there a better way to manage versions and avoid branching within SharePoint?

A few things to note:

1. The modelling files are around 40 MB each.
2. I'm completely new to SharePoint.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want to make changes to a file on a site and you want to make sure no one else can edit it, check out the file. When you have the file checked out, you can edit it online or offline, and save it—multiple times, if necessary.
When you finish editing and check the file back into the library, other people can see your changes and edit the file, if they have permission. And, if you decide not to make or keep any changes in the file, you can simply discard your checkout so you don’t affect version history.

Reference:

[Check out, check in, or discard changes to files in a library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/check-out-check-in-or-discard-changes-to-files-in-a-library-7e2c12a9-a874-4393-9511-1378a700f6de)

2.[Enable and configure versioning for a list or library.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-1555d642-23ee-446a-990a-bcab618c7a37)

Comment: The issue is that it's not clear to me what is being checked back in. Is it the file in the original location where I downloaded it from Sharepoint? Can I select a different file/location to check back in?

Comment: The file in the original location where I downloaded it from SharePoint. You cannot select a different location to check back in.